# Unexpectedly removed from a SE. How to enquire for the reasons?

Tags: support

I am using the SE app. Clicking on the achievement button I see a line stating " SE xxxx -10 user removed ".

I did very little activity on that SE and received very few upvotes.

I was never unpolite nor involved in sensitive topics or debates, especially because the SE topic in itself is unlikely to led to misbehaviour.

Does it really means that I have been removed and especially it is normal to be removed without warning or a more explicative notification?

Can I contact the moderator(s) of a specific SE and, if yes, how?

Comment: You haven’t been removed. Another user was removed. That user had voted up one of your answers (or maybe 2 if your questions, etc), which had given you 10 points.  Since the user was removed, that vote was invalidated, so the points you earned from it were also removed. This happens when a user quits, or is removed by the mods for other reasons (for example, when they catch a sock puppet account). It has nothing to do with your behavior. Unless it was your sock puppet account ;)

Comment: @Dan Bron. Thank you. It was not a drama but I felt it disturbing :). May I ask what a sock puppet account is?

Comment: @Alchimista One human being having multiple accounts each pretending to be a separate, indivisible human being. Possibly voting on each others’ posts or even engaging in “conversation”. Like you would with a sock puppet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens - you didn't do anything wrong. A user who upvoted you got deleted, either cause they acted inappropriately or simply chose to delete their account.

Since votes are *mostly* anonymous (we can't tell who voted for a specific post - but there's safeguards for voting fraud in place) - no one can tell you *who* was removed.

Its not you - its someone else. That said, I have no idea what *actually* happens when a user's on the SE app and gets deleted but chances are it wouldn't be that.

I'd suggest confirming on the mobile web page (or the regular one) if you were still worried.

Assuming you *did* get deleted, and it was a mistake, things get messy. You'd likely need to use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the site - calmly and politely explain what happened and if someone made a mistake, they'll get someone from SE to fix it. Otherwise, presumably someone will let you know.

Comment: Ok now it is clear. Wasn't me.